# apply js to 3rd party web pages using iframes or something else

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is it possible to load different 3rd party web pages and apply a js script to each one?

Suppose we want to first load yahoo.com, and then get the innerHTML of the body and do something with it, and then load google.com and again get the innerHTML of the body and do something with it?

Comment: Most sites like google dont allow their pages to be loaded in an iframe. Also browser security mechanisms dont allow manipulating pages that are not loaded from the same origin/domain.

Comment: suppose we have a domain that does allow their pages to be loaded in an iframe.  Can we load different pages and apply our own js to each one? (the js would be the same for each page)

Comment: If it were allowed it would be a pretty large security challenge - i.e. manipulate that page to send me your credit card information you just entered in type things

Comment: @mark schultheiss not sure I follow the security issue.  I load a page from the web, I don't have access to anyone else's credit card information.  I apply some js to the page.

Comment: Scraping content off a page is different than running it ON the page - like an "input" event handler to send someone's input from anther sites page to yours.